# Error on loading visualforce site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, ajax, instance

I have sites on multiple orgs which have a visualforce page. On this visualforce page in an `apex:actionFunction` with a rerender and an oncomplete.

The idea is to have a spinner on the page until the rerender is finished, and then the oncomplete will remove the spinner.

The problem is that (most times, rarely I'll refresh and it will work) the spinner never goes away. But the weird thing is that it only happens in some orgs. It seems to be related to an error displayed in chrome dev console:

> 3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript?rel=1669236224000:111         GET https://abc.my.salesforce-sites.com/jslibrary/jslabels/1669553631000/en_AU.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

If it does happen to work on a refresh, this error is not printed. It also doesn't display in the orgs where it works.

Out of 4 orgs, in the 2 orgs where this problem happens I've noticed that the instance is AUSxx and the 2 orgs where it works are APxx. (scratchorgs (CSxx) also work fine). So I think this might be related to the issues.

What's causing this issue and how can I fix or workaround it?

On further investigation it seems like in https://abcd.my.salesforce-sites.com/faces/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript?rel=1669236224000 when it works it's because it finds a matching script in oldscripts. When it fails to work there's no match and it tries to `head.appendChild(script)` which ends up failing. Looking at all the values of script in oldscripts it seems like the number has changed.

src nosessionhref = `'/jslibrary/jslabels/1669759115000/en_AU.js'`

oldscripts[4] nosessionhref = `'/jslibrary/jslabels/1669551527000/en_AU.js'`

The slightly different numbers appear to be the cause of the issue. but I have no idea where these come from or how to change it (or if it's even the actual cause of the issue).

Answer (score 1):

This post was made 9 months ago and when we found ourselves in exactly the same situation, we turned to Salesforce Support for help. Here's their answer:

> Remove "en_GB" as the default language attribute on the VF page and
> instead utilize the Guest User as the default. Override this setting
> on the page for languages other than English for translation purposes.
>
> Maintain the "language" attribute on the VF page, but set the default
> value to empty, like so: "language="". This will prompt the VF page to
> disregard the attribute and use the values of the guest user.
>
> Set the language of the site's guest user to 'English'.
>
> Set the locale of the site's guest user to 'English (United Kingdom)'.

I hope this helps someone else who is experiencing the same issue!

~ Nick

Comment: haha I also went to support, so many messages and even screensharing sessions for nothing. glad you managed to squeeze an answer out of them.